# How can you determine if an iOS device supports airdrop

Tags: ios, uiactivity, airdrop, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I'm scratching my head trying to determine how to detect if a device supports airdrop. My thinking was to try to get the UIActivity for airdrop and call canPerformWithActivityItems: on it. The problem is I can't figure out how to get the UIActivity for airdrop, anybody know how to do this? Does anybody have a different approach to solve this problem?

Thanks,
   Omri

Comment: Curious - why do you need to know? If you use `UIActivityController` it will appear or not. Generally you don't need to know ahead of time.

Comment: @rmaddy I've run into this when I wanted to add an actual "Airdrop" button in the app.  (Vs. a share button)

Comment: I've also run into this issue because I'm trying to share content exclusively with AirDrop

Answer (score 2):

There's no API that exposes this information, since UIActivityViewController won't expose the system's UIActivity objects.

Unfortunately, the only way to get this information is to check for device support.

From [the Apple support website](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5887):

> To share content with AirDrop, both users need one of the following
>   devices using iOS 7:
>
> - iPhone 5 or later
> - iPad (4th generation)
> - iPad mini
> - iPod touch (5th generation)
>
> AirDrop transfers information using Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.
>   You need an iCloud account to share with Contacts.

You can detect this in a number of ways.  If you don't have existing code that does this, check out [the EPPZDevice class](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit/blob/master/eppz!kit/EPPZDevice.h) which will do most of the work for you.